# Grab more than one category with wordpress $args

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'category' => 15 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

The issue is that I want to grab more than just category number 15. Simply add them next to 15 like 15, 18 or "15,18" does not work.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: use '15,18' : it will works, i have already answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: it is work in my project.

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'category' => '15,8');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: it works. I thought I tried this, but I did something wrong. Thanks.